# C# multiple attributes used as requirement

Tags: c#, attributes

So I have been attempting to create a mod and i have run into an issue with attempting to require more than one skill set, or rather to restrict more than one skill set.

What I am attempting to do i lock it down so that players can only gain access to one skill tree at a time.  What I have that works is the following but it doesn't stop them from taking skills in another tree.

```
namespace Test.run.TechTree
{
    using System;
    using System.Runtime.Serialization;
    using Test.Gameplay.Components;
    using Test.Gameplay.DynamicValues;
    using Test.Gameplay.Items;
    using Test.Gameplay.Players;
    using Test.Gameplay.Property;
    using Test.Gameplay.Skills;
    using Test.Gameplay.Systems.TextLinks;
    using Test.Shared.Services;
    using Test.Shared.Utils;
    using Gameplay.Systems.Tooltip;

    [DataContract]

    [RequiresSkill(typeof(FireSkill), 0)]
    public partial class ShootingSkill : Skill
    {
        public override string FriendlyName { get { return "Shooting"; } }
        public override string Description { get { return "This is how you shoot"; } }

        public static int[] SkillPointCost = { 1, 2, 2, 3, 3 };
        public override int RequiredPoint { get { return this.Level < this.MaxLevel ? SkillPointCost[this.Level] : 0; } }
        public override int MaxLevel { get { return 4; } }
    }

}
```

This allows them to learn and put points into this skill tree, which is great, but I want to restrict it so that if they have already been learning skills in another skill tree that they can not put skills into this skill tree.  Ultimately I would like to be able to say that you can take this skill if you have not put points into the other or until you have at least 50 points in the other.

In this example the player wants to start putting points into the Fireskill of the shooting skill tree, but I want to say that if they have between 1 to 49 in Gearskill part of the Accessories skill tree that I do not want them to be able to use this until they have either not put anything into the Gearskill or at least 50 into it.  I will admit I am pretty new to C# and still learning more about attributes but how could I get the concept that I have below to work.  Any help would be appreciated.

```
namespace Test.run.TechTree
{
    using System;
    using System.Runtime.Serialization;
    using Test.Gameplay.Components;
    using Test.Gameplay.DynamicValues;
    using Test.Gameplay.Items;
    using Test.Gameplay.Players;
    using Test.Gameplay.Property;
    using Test.Gameplay.Skills;
    using Test.Gameplay.Systems.TextLinks;
    using Test.Shared.Services;
    using Test.Shared.Utils;
    using Gameplay.Systems.Tooltip;

    [DataContract]

    [RequiresSkill(typeof(FireSkill), 0), RequiresSkill(typeof(GearSkill), >1 or  <50]
    public partial class ShootingSkill : Skill
    {
        public override string FriendlyName { get { return "Shooting"; } }
        public override string Description { get { return "This is how you shoot"; } }

        public static int[] SkillPointCost = { 1, 2, 2, 3, 3 };
        public override int RequiredPoint { get { return this.Level < this.MaxLevel ? SkillPointCost[this.Level] : 0; } }
        public override int MaxLevel { get { return 4; } }
    }

}
```

Comment: Here is the error I recive "Duplicate 'RequiresSkill' attribute (CS0579)"

Answer (score 1):

You need to set `AllowMultiple = true` for `RequiresSkill` attribute.

```
[AttributeUsage(AttributeTargets.{whatever}, AllowMultiple = true)]  
public class RequiresSkill : Attribute  
{  
}
```

Comment: ok got all of that, now to figure out the {whatever} portion I tried RequiredSkills but it throws a 

'System.AttributeTargets' does not contain a definition for 'RequiredSkill' (CS0117)....I am still learning sorry

Comment: I think it's time to look at your `RequiredSkill` definition. Please update you question with it. Also you can shorten you original post by removing first code snippet, it's unnecessary.

Comment: I changed it to all but now i get 'Test.Mods.TechTree.RequiresSkill' does not contain a constructor that takes 2 arguments (CS1729)

Comment: I won't lie, I am a little lost with where to find the definitions

Comment: What? Just do a 'go to definition' in Visual studio.

Comment: guess i should download Visual Studio then, been doing most of this in unity or notepad++

Comment: Aah.. no don't download VS just for that. That would be an over-overkill. Just use sublime > open folder (your project dir) and 'find' in 'all files'.

Comment: Ok I found the definitions and it was a class, I made the change but now i get about 200 messages for 'Test.Mods.TechTree.RequiresSkill' does not contain a constructor that takes 2 arguments, this is happening for multiple other skills and items

Comment: is there an easier way to deal with the attributes in the class, like saying if fireskill =0 and gearskill is >1 or greater than 50 then { get { return "Shooting"; } }